# node http.get not fired

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I trying to have a loop with http.get requests - and I don't know why the function doesn't starts.
my code is :

```
while(List.length>0) {                
   if(counter < Limit) { // Limit is the amount of requests I want to 
        counter++;
        inProcess++;
        var scanitem =  List.pop();

      var body = "";    
      var url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'+scanitem;
      var options = {
                      path: url,                                                
                      method: 'GET'
                    };
      console.log(url); // This part is happenning
      var _request =  https.get(options, function (res) {
                       console.log('get web site');// this part is NOT showup. 
                       res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                          console.log(chunk); // this part is NOT showup. 
                          body += chunk.toString();            
                      });
                      res.on("end", function() {                            
                        console.log(body);// this part is NOT showup. 
                      });
                      res.on("error", function(error) {                         
                       console.log('error')// this part is NOT showup. 
                      });
                  });
       _request.end();         
   }                                        
   else {
      console.log('list BREAK');} // This part is happenning after the limit crossed
```

Comment: You can first add `_request.on("error", function(error)` to find out any errorrs. Since if request itself may fail before any response is sent, no response error will show up.

Comment: https requests may require key or certificates. Since you are not giving any server may reject the request itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When passing an `Object` as the 1st argument, the URL should be broken up into individual pieces:

   ```
   var options = {
       method: 'GET',
       protocol: 'https:',
       hostname: 'www.mywebsite.com',
       path: '/' + scanitem
   };

   var _request = https.get(options, ...);
   ```

   The `options` that are used are covered under [`https.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback), which `https.get()` is a convenience variant of.

   You can also pass the URL `String`, which `https.get()` will be run through [`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) for you:

   ```
   var _request = https.get(url, ...);
   ```
2. JavaScript doesn't have block-scoped variables ([yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)). So, despite the location of `var body = "";`, every iteration of your `while` loop is still appending to the same `body`.

   This isn't as much a concern when the variable is only used by synchronous tasks, like `scanitem`, `url`, and `options` are. But, when mixing in asynchronous tasks like `https.get()`, you won't likely get the result you're expecting.

   In the current absence of block-scoped variables, you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) to create an additional `function` scope.

   As `List` appears to be an `Array`, you can use an iterator `function` with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for this:

   ```
   List.forEach(function (scanitem) {
       var body = '';
       var url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'+scanitem;

       https.get(url, function (res) {
           // etc.
       });
   });
   ```

   And, for the `Limit`, you can use `.splice()` to remove and work with the portion of the `Array` you want:

   ```
   List.splice(0, Limit).forEach(function (scanitem) {
       // etc.
   });
   ```

---

Also, unlike with `https.request()`, you're not required to call `_request.end()` when using `https.get()`.

Comment: still doesn't work, when I take it out of the loop, its working fine, but when its part of a process - it's somehow don't start the request.